# Uses for leftover potatoes from a pot-roast

Tags: culinary-uses, potatoes, pot-roast

I made a large pot-roast with sweet onion, carrots, green beans, mushrooms and Yukon Gold potatoes (all cooked in the same pot).  All the vegetables except for the potatoes got devoured, so now I have a lot of leftover, slightly beefy, potatoes.  What would be a good use for them?

Comment: So what did you end up making with them?

Comment: @Martha: steak fries -- cut into wedges, tossed in olive oil, salt and pepper,  sprinkled with paprika and baked -- my (current) favorite way to prepare potatoes.  They didn't come out as well as usual because they were already cooked instead of put in the oven raw, but still tasty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn into mashed potatoes for tomorrow night's dinner?

If you have some roast left, too, cut it down into bite-sized bits, add back in some more vegetables, and turn it into a sort of shepard's pie-type meal.  (stew-like dish covered with mashed potatoes, then baked)

Comment: Great idea; I love shepherd's pie.  I don't have enough meat left for it this time though.

Comment: Love the idea for shepherd's pie, that would be tasty!

Comment: Another great idea after they are mashed is to make potato pancakes, mmm.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how mushy the potatoes are, you could also chop them up and saute with some onions and meat for a nice hash.

Comment: Or just sauteed on their own with some soft cheese melted over them...

Answer (score 2):

I just made burritos out of leftover pot roast, of course I had beef leftover too.  Beef, potatoes, a bit of cheese and I happened to have sour cream in the fridge.  Instant burrito, with an out of place pot roast taste.  The mind expected a barbacoa taste from that texture in a burrito, but got regular pot roast.

More regularly if I hadn't had just that combination to make burritos, I'd probably dice them and add them to a breakfast meal.  The meaty taste will fit in just fine with an egg breakfast.  Add them to the eggs or just heat them up on the skillet real quick, should be great either way.